# Bootstrap dropdownlist z-index displaying under modal window footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some styling problems with bootstrap.

I have a small modal window containing a dropdown. However I can't seem to get the dropdown to display over the footer of the window.

I have played with the zindex of the dropdown ensuring it was higher than the windows but no luck.

Can anyone suggest what I should be changing?

The html

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="store-modal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 id="reward-title">Select Store</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>
        Please select the store you are working from
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    @foreach (var model in Model)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="store" data-id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.StoreId)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.StoreName)</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>

    </p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste some HTML and CSS

Comment: also worth checking the parent containers have overflow visible.

Answer (score 3):

You just add a class having `z-index` as attribute having higher than model box footer.

For z-index to work, you also have to set position = relative, absolute, or fixed. Also putting z-index something like 5000 might help. (the modal may have z index higher than the 2000's.

so in your css i would add this:

```
.class-of-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

.modal-body class has a overflow-y: auto property. You might need to change this to:

```
.modal-body {
    overflow-y:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your setting the z-index of the drop down make sure it is positioned.  Meaning it has either position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed.

Comment: Hi Kevin I did try setting the position: relative; before posting but all it did was stretch the window down