# Chosen dropdown list Z index issue with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, z-index, jquery-chosen

The chosen dropdown list always goes underneath the next available card element on the model.

I have tried

```
.class-of-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
}
.modal-body {
    overflow-y:visible;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scpoh0te/31/) example.

[image]

I have tried several fixes and none of them seems working.

[Chosen dropdown within Bootstrap modal is hidden behind modal footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768382/chosen-dropdown-within-bootstrap-modal-is-hidden-behind-modal-footer)

[How to Solve Option Select appeared behind modal using bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129362/how-to-solve-option-select-appeared-behind-modal-using-bootstrap)

[Bootstrap dropdownlist z-index displaying under modal window footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274060/bootstrap-dropdownlist-z-index-displaying-under-modal-window-footer)

[how to make chosen select go over parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271804/how-to-make-chosen-select-go-over-parent-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CSS that is causing this problem. After the modal opens, there is a div called "Another Heading" which has a class called `card`. This `card` class has a default scss which is causing the problem;

```
.accordion > .card{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

The solution is just to write the CSS given below to override this CSS;

```
.accordion > .card{
   overflow: inherit;
}
```